# Universality of $a{\wedge\neg}b$ gate and similar

Tags: boolean-algebra

According to the Wikipedia and other sources only NAND/NOR make one-element sets that are functionally complete. Then, there are also a lot of two-element functional complete sets.
Question: why $a{\wedge\neg}b$ (and similarly ${\neg}a{\wedge}b$ and duals like $a{\vee\neg}b$ and ${\neg}a{\vee}b$) are not considered universal gates? Yes, they violate at least one of Post's criterion for universality (i.e. $a{\wedge\neg}b$ is falsity-preserving), but, is this so important? You can build a NOT gate and an AND gate out of one any above mentioned gates, thus, making them universal.
Where am I mistaken? :)

Comment: You are mistaken. You cannot build a NOT gate, because NOT is not falsity-preserving ... Try building a NOT gate and you'll see. Notice that $a\wedge \neg a$ is equivalent to FALSE, not to $\neg a$.

Comment: in a∧¬b set a to truth? the gate is, basically, a CNOT and a basis for universal computation in cellular automatons (i.e. glider collision is in accordance to this function)

Comment: You cannot set $a$ to TRUE unless you have previously shown TRUE to be in your generated system (and it isn't, since TRUE is not falsity-preserving ...)

Comment: ooooooh. that means that my functionally complete set would be {truth, a∧¬b} ?

Comment: Yes, indeed.    This one is functionally complete

Comment: thanks. you can write this as an answer and i'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken. You cannot build a NOT gate, because NOT is not falsity-preserving ... Try building a NOT gate and you'll see. Notice that a∧¬a
is equivalent to FALSE, not to ¬a

Comment: But wait, don't we have T and F values always available to us? There always has to be an input to these operators, right?

Comment: No, T and F are not necessarily available. Notice that the gate which always returns T is not the same thing as the value T itself.

Comment: Maybe my understandings of mathematics are very poor, but how values "exist" then? And why there is a difference between value T and gate, that returns T? What is then connected, for instance, to the NAND gate as "nothing", for it initially to produce T? (...which is then used to produce F).
Could you recommend something to read on this topic?